# for in loop is only storing the last data in the Map

Tags: flutter, for-loop

This is the code that im developing to get a collection from Firestore and store all its data in another map

```
onPressed: () async {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('primary').get() .then((values) {
    for (var I in values.docs) {
      data.addAll(i.data());
    }
    print(data);
  });
},
```

if I just print i.id, I will get all 9 ids that are available. But, by doing this to copy all the data from the map, when I print the `Map data`, Im only Storting the last value. Ive tried to use forEach but happened the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make `data` a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` instead of `Map<String, dynamic>` so you can add values to it instead of overwriting it the whole time.

So do this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = {};
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('primary').get().then((snapshots) {
    for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {
      data.add(doc.data());
    }
  });
  print(data);
},
```